# Pop up Message Box to open on a specific date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where i have to swap certain cells every 4 weeks, is there a way to have a message box appear to remind me when i open my workbook on a certain date which i would put in a cell in one of my worksheets?

Comment: Sure, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the last date in a named cell called "important date". Then write the following code in ThisWorkbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    if now > [important_date]+28 then
        msgbox "Change me, please"
    end if

end sub
```

Once you are reminded, make sure to change the date in the named cell "important_date". Here you can read for named ranges: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823060.aspx

Comment: I've tried this but the message box doesn't appear when i open the workbook, i set the important date cell as a date in October.

Comment: I found out where i went wrong, I was adding the code to my module rather than the workbook. Sorry for my stupidity. Thank You so much for your help.

Comment: Super. If you liked the answer, feel free to mark is at accepted and to give it +1, when you can:) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work